# Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm working in Cloud9, following a tutorial. I've got to the point where I'm trying load the data within mongo to the view. The table structure seems to get generated but no data is populated.

From Chrome I see the following:

```
 Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else
```

And the response from the page load within Chrome is:

```
0: {undefined: {}}
1: {undefined: {}}
2: {undefined: {}}
3: {undefined: {}}
4: {undefined: {}}
```

My View

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Reason</th>
  <th>Actions</th>
  <th>Requester</th>
  <th>Verified</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="change in changes">
    <td>{{ change.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ change.reason }}</td>
    <td>{{ change.actions }}</td>
    <td>{{ change.requester }}</td>
    <td>{{ change.verified }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My Controller

```
'use strict';

/**
* @ngdoc function
* @name clientApp.controller:ChangeCtrl
* @description
* # ChangeCtrl
* Controller of the clientApp
*/
angular.module('clientApp')
    .controller('ChangeCtrl', function ($scope, Change) {
        $scope.changes = Change.getList().$object;
    });
```

My APP.JS

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name clientApp
 * @description
 * # clientApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */

angular.module('clientApp', ['ngRoute', 'restangular']).config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://changebg-MYUSERNAME.c9.io/#:8080');

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    })
    .when('/change', {
        templateUrl: 'views/change.html',
        controller: 'ChangeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}).factory('ChangeRestangular', function (Restangular) {

    return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
            id: '_id'
        });
    });

}).factory('Change', function (ChangeRestangular) {

    return ChangeRestangular.service('change');

});
```

I'm sure this is something simple but I just can't see it!

Thanks

Comment: is this `Change.getList().$oject` correct?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected this and I get the same result.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case) out

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems like the error is raised when the data returned by your external resource is not an array but something else  (which is kinda obvious), you should either update your external rest resource to return an array (you can check the dev tools network tab to see what the rest resource is returning) or change the query type from `getList` to `one` [error source](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/master/src/restangular.js#L1058)

Comment: If I use the POSTMAN extension then the api returns all results as expected. If i append the url with one of the IDs using POSTMAN it returns again as expected a single result.

Comment: When you say look at the dev tools (i'm using chrome) network tab. What results am i looking at? change.html or change.js? I can see that change.html shows undefined as at the top of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that I have removed the restangular for now until i understand if further. I have gone back to basics which has worked for me.

Thanks again